# split the string containing backward slash and replace with forward slash

Tags: c#

I have a string which contains backward slashes and I want to reply it with forward slashes

```
            string filename = "te\test";
            var x = filename.Split('\\');
             Console.WriteLine(filename);
            Console.ReadLine();
```

I have tried something like this but it is getting the same string "te\test" into x.

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: but when u split string then u will get back array na then store it to array and try to print it. and try to print like array na that will work i think.

Comment: it's just giving back what i declared not an array

Comment: try to print this x[0] or x[1].

Comment: its just giving x[0] which is again "te\test"

Comment: but u have that data in string right? but try to save that data according to the Javascript na make function with string input and spilt it let me show example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You original string is not:

```
te\test
```

it's:

```
te{tab}est
```

`\t` is the tab character. So you can't split on the `\` because you original string doesn't have a `\`

If you do something like this:

```
    string filename = "te\\test";
    var x = filename.Split('\\');
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join("/",x));
```

You'll get the result you wanted.

But you really don't need to `Split` and `Join` when you can just `Replace`:

```
Console.WriteLine(filename.Replace('\\','/'));
```

Note: you can use `@` with your original string to make it a literal string (escapes are ignored) as @Joeb454 suggests (and that's usually what I'll do), but unfortunately the same trick doesn't apply to chars so you can't, for example, do `@'\'`.

Comment: I completely forgot about replace while writing my answer! For the example in question, it's actually a much better solution than doing a split and then doing a join again.

Answer (score 2):

Your initial string appears to be wrong, you're escaping the 't', giving you a tab character, it should be `string filename = "te\\test";`

You could also declare it as `string filename = @"te\test";` - preceding the string with the @ sign indicates to the compiler that it's a literal string, and therefore nothing will be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

```
string filename = "te\test";
string[] x = filename.Split('\\');
Console.WriteLine(filename);//this line should be Console.WriteLine(x[0]+X[1]);
Console.ReadLine();
```

But I think you are looking for

```
filename = filename.Replace("\\","/");
Console.WriteLine(filename);
```